# jQuery Selector last on a Knockout Page

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

On click of a button a my HTML page, I add data to an observable array and knockout displays it on the page. I have put commas(,) in the html to get a comma separated set.

However, I should clear the last comma. I add a comma using a span with a class  .

I use the jquery selector for a class with the last option to set the inner html to an empty string. However it clears all the commas.

If I use first as an option it does clear the first comma.  However, I want the last one to be removed.

```
$(".spanSeparator:last")[0].innerHTML = "";
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mayurarora/ZtL8t/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to solve your problem completely incorrect way. Just use KO's computed to format your data store any way you like:

```
viewModel.formattedDataStore = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.dataStore().join(", ");
}, viewModel);
```

This computed returns all elements of the data store glued by comma. Now this computed may be bound to `<span>` with simple *text* binding.

```
<span >{</span>
<span data-bind='text:formattedDataStore'></span>
<span>}</span>
```

Voisla! Now it's not necessary to change your output through `.innerHTML`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZtL8t/1/

Comment: super! Thank you much. Just a couple of things...any thoughts on why jQuery last did not work..and you added this computed observable outside the viewmodel. I tried adding it inside but got some reference errors. Can you show me how would you do this inside the view model?   Thanks a lot.

Comment: Obviously that `.innerHTML = ""` statement was being executed before `foreach` binding rendered list of elements. There is special way to modify output of `foreach` binding - option `afterRender` (see KO docs about `foreach`).
So there is no elegant way to define computed inside `var viewModel = { ... }` since there is no way to pass still undefined viewModel as context for computed. You should consider to use constructor instead of defining plain object through `var`.